# How to access a nested field in struct in Golang

Tags: go, struct

Let's say I have this structblock:

```
type AllShipments struct {
    Shipments []struct {
        ShipmentID    int       `json:"shipmentId"`
        ShipmentDate  time.Time `json:"shipmentDate"`
        ShipmentItems []struct {
            OrderItemID string `json:"orderItemId"`
            OrderID     string `json:"orderId"`
        } `json:"shipmentItems"`
        Transport struct {
            TransportID int `json:"transportId"`
        } `json:"transport"`
    } `json:"shipments"`
}
```

I use:

```
func main() {
    var t AllShipments
    .....
    .....
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &t)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(string(body))
    }

    prettyJSON, err := json.MarshalIndent(t, "", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to generate json", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(prettyJSON))
```

How to get for example only the json field "shipmentDate", I tried `t.Shipments.ShipmentDate` but that did not work. `t.Shipments` did work to filter out the first array. So what is the best way to do that? I know I can disable the other json fields with `"json:-"` but that is not what I am looking for. Just a way to access that field

Comment: You need to index into the slice to access its elements. Please take the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1), slices and other basics are covered there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`t.Shipments` is a slice - so to access any of it's elements you must pass an index - and then you can access that element's fields e.g.

```
if len(t.Shipments) > 0 {
    fmt.Println(v.Shipments[0].ShipmentDate)
}
```

or to range over the slice:

```
for i, v := range t.Shipments {
    fmt.Println(i, v.ShipmentDate)
}
```